# how to get an icon from external site?

Tags: php

This code:

```
<?php echo $value['symbol-icon']?
```

Could output (example) :

```
09
```

How could I display the icon number **09**  from this url http://yr.github.io/weather-symbols/ using php?

09 = rain icon

01d = sun

if 09 then show rain icon

if 01d then show sun icon

Answer (score 5):

You need to generate an `img` tag whose "src" is the correct URL. You can use the variable to construct part of the URL, so it points to the exact file you want. For example:

```
<img src="http://yr.github.io/weather-symbols/png/100/<?php echo $value['symbol-icon'];?>.png" />
```